# Setting a Connection time out in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I want to know how to set the **Timeout** in milliseconds for **HTTP Samplers** that are generated by using recording controller. Is there any way to configure this at one place, so that it will be applied to all requests and what is the default Connection Timeout time and Response Timeout time in JMeter?

Highly appreciates any helps or ideas

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a way possible to do this. You need to add a **'HTTP Request Default'** configuration element from **'Configuration Elements'** option i.e. Right click test plan and add this **'HTTP Request Default'**.

In this **'HTTP Request Default'**  there is an option **Connect** in **'Timeouts (milliseconds)'**, you can specify your connection timeout value in this field and it will be applied to all child samplers. If this 'HTTP Request Default' is added at **Test Plan** level then it will be applied to all samplers and all thread groups.

[image]

If you want to specify individual Connection Timeout, then you can specify it in same field of each sampler. Individual sampler Connection timeout will **override** the 'HTTP Request Default' connection timeout value.

[image]

One more way is there but I haven't used that, you can specify this value in **JMeter.properties** file located at bin directory.

```
# set the socket timeout (or use the parameter http.socket.timeout)
# Value is in milliseconds
#httpclient.timeout=0
# 0 == no timeout
```

Uncomment the **'httpclient.timeout'** property and specify its value. I have used the 'HTTP Request Default' solution and it works, but not used properties file solution, so you should check its effect using **Table Listener** before actually using it.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dhiman, but here in my test plan I was generated the http samples by using recording controller . So there is no HttpRequestDefualts, then how to add this time out for samplers generated by Recording controller

Comment: This option 'HTTP Request Default' still should be available as this doesn't depend on whether you have used Recording controller or not, as this is on Test plan level. If after recording the script you are not getting this option (for any reason), then create a new test plan, add 'HTTP Request Default' & 'Recording Controller' and then copy-paste your script in this new test plan.

Comment: Yeah, I have not found the HTTPRequestDefault. I am going to do what you said, but here small query i.e,. Is it required to mention the Server/ip address and Port ??

Comment: No it is not required to mention Server IP address and port, these values will be taken from the individual sample requests. Any value which is not specified in HTTPRequestDefault will be taken from individual samples and it is not mandatory to define all values in HTTPRequestDefault.